# Writing variables and list to csv in the same row

Tags: python, list, csv, variables, row

I've been trying to write variables and list to a csv file, here is the thing:

```
import csv

foo=bar
foo1=bar2
list=[element,element2,element3]

with open('file.csv', 'w',newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow([foo,list,foo1])
```

If I do that when I open the csv I have this, that I don't really want:

```
bar,[element,element2,element3], bar2
```

I want the ending result to be:

```
bar,element,element2,element3, bar2
```

It is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by appending the lists when calling `writerow`:

```
import csv

foo=bar
foo1=bar2
list=[element,element2,element3]

with open('file.csv', 'w',newline='') as f:
   writer = csv.writer(f)
   writer.writerow([foo]+list+[foo1]) # Changed this line
```

Comment: Thanks GoodDeeds!! i knew there was a way, i just couldnt find anything relate to it, it works like a charm :)